# find_or_create Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, methods, ruby-on-rails-4, find

I have a simple CSV import Method:

```
  def import
    Player.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to players_path, notice: "Players Imported successfully"
  end
```

```
  def self.import(file)
    SmarterCSV.process(file.path) do |chunk|
      chunk.each do |h|
        h[:gr_name] = CGI::unescape(h[:gr_name]).force_encoding('UTF-8')
      end
      # Player.create(chunk.first) 
      # Find if player already exists, then update attributes else create new Player
    end
  end
```

The variable i'm checking against is "**gr_id**", but i can't implement it right.

Basically i need something like

```
player = Player.find_by_id(row["gr_id"]) || new
Player.create(chunk.first)
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming gr_id equals the player id you can use the following:

```
Player.find_or_create_by(id: row['gr_id'])
```

Example of active record finders in Rails 4: http://rails4guides.com/articles/rails-4-activerecord-finders

Comment: I tried that, undefined local variable or method `row' for #<Class:0x007fb8a0c59738>

Comment: That is because you haven't defined a row yet. After doing so the finder works great. What does chunk contain?

Comment: The complete import code is what i have in my Question, how do i define a row?. Chunk contains every hash in a row (1 | 2 | 3 | 4).
So if 1 is :test we can h[:test] etc.

Comment: Usually I use the foreach method which loops over all rows. Anyway, chunk sounds like your row. I would rename chunk to row.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
       Player.find_or_create_by(name: row['name'], status: row['status']
      end
      # Player.create(chunk.first) 
      # Find if player already exists, then update attributes else create new Player
    end
  end
```

This is assuming Player has attributes name and status and the headers in the CSV file is so named.